# Why the program can not read run() method?

Tags: android

I write this program but when i run this program, the program can't read run() method because not show log.e() in logCat and not show message in textView. Why?

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

private TextView textModifiedThread;
private int threadModifiedInt=4;
private Point threadModifiedPoint=new Point(20,10);
boolean activeThread=true;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.e("CREATE", "READ");

    textModifiedThread=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textId);
    Thread currentThread=new Thread(){
        public void Run(){
            Log.e("RUN", "READ");
            try{
                threadModifiedInt=20;
                threadModifiedPoint.set(30, 40);

                int timeCounter=100;
                while(activeThread&&(timeCounter>0)){
                    try {
                        sleep(100);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if(timeCounter%10==0){
                        threadHandler.sendEmptyMessage((int)timeCounter/10);
                        Log.e("WHile", "Read");
                    }
                    timeCounter--;
                }
            }finally{
                finish();
            }
        }
    };        
    currentThread.start();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
    if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        activeThread=false;
        Log.e("TOUCH", "READ");
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
private Handler threadHandler=new Handler(){
    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg){
        textModifiedThread.setText("test int is "+threadModifiedInt+"\ntest    point is "+threadModifiedPoint.toString()+"\ncounter is "+Integer.toString(msg.what));
        Log.e("ERROR", "Read this");
    }
};
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <LinearLayout 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:orientation="vertical" 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
<TextView 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/textId"/> 
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try applying @Override on your `Run` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because you misspelled the run word:

```
public void Run(){
```

Run has to be lowercase. So the correct method is:

```
public void run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use Runnable Thread instead. 
And your public void Run() try change it to  `public void run()`. 
This is probably the cause of it.

```
Thread currentThread=new Thread(new Runnable){
    public void run(){

    }
 }
```